# Reading and writing large csv matlab vs. r

Tags: r, matlab, csv

I'm currently running a script that reads about 8500 csv files(8.3mb each) and appends a column from csv if certain conditions are met. The csv files only contain numbers, except the headings and space delimited.

My R script uses fread and then converts data tables to matrices before using write.table to enhance speed. 
Running the script for 2160 files (about 17GB) resulted  in a 3.8 GB csv file and took about 3.2 hours. Fread for each file takes from 3-4 seconds.

I'm considering writing a matlab script as I noticed matlab also has fread and saving to mat format can save time. Can using matlab significantly decrease the time read and writing to csv?

Comment: Try it on subset of your data and see, that's all one of us would do.

Comment: Check your ram and then try multiple intances of r

Answer (score 3):

Matlab's `fread` is completely unrelated to R's.  R's is an advanced data reading function capable of handling structured data like `csv`, Matlab's is a low-level binary file reader that isn't intended for handling text data at all, not to mention structured text data.

Unfortunately, Matlab's `csv` handling capabilities are limited.  If you are on Windows and have Microsoft Office installed, then it can use Excel to parse complex csv files (although you can run into limitations regarding how many rows or columns it supports).  If not, then none of Matlab's functions that are supposed to handle `csv` files are actually able to handle all standards-compliant `csv` files, meaning there is a good chance you will have to write your own `csv` parser if your data has things like non-numeric data, missing data, comments, quotes, etc.

You can find more details on the problem on this article: [MATLAB can’t read plain text data out of a wet paper bag.](https://abandonmatlab.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/matlab-cant-read-plain-text-data-out-of-a-wet-paper-bag/)

Comment: The link you provided... the title made me laugh my @$$ off.  +1 for solid internals knowledge.

Comment: How does using mex-based compilers to read csv's on matlab compare with fread on r?

Comment: mex files are basically just C, C++, or Fortran files.  If you are going to write your own `csv` parser in C/C++ or Fortran, then it probably doesn't matter a huge amount whether you use R or MATLAB (you can probably even include interfaces for both).